# readr: extract value from column

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr, rlang

I am using `readr`'s `read_delim` like so:

```
focals <- read_delim('~/all_focals2.txt', delim='\t', 
                     col_names=c("1", "focal", "2", "model"),
                     col_types=cols_only(focal = col_double(), model = col_character()))
```

In my data, the 'focal' column contains data like:

```
55.0 mm
7.8 mm
16.0 mm
```

and so on. I want to get the data as a double, so I want to ignore the ' mm' postfix.

I found [this bug comment](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/250#issuecomment-142372863), which seems to suggest this is actually not possible today in `readr`, except by reading the columns as string then converting as a second step.

However, I can only assume there must be a way to write custom column specifications, right? It's probably possible to write your own `col_focal_length()` function, which builds upon `col_double()` behind the scenes, to achieve correct parsing from the get go?

**EDIT** Solution by overwriting:

```
focals$focal <- as.double(gsub(" mm$", "", focals$focal))
```

But as I said, I'd like to have it right from the get go in the dataset...

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
        as.double(parse_number(focals$focal))
```

If this works let us know. Thank you

Comment: I think it's what I called 'a solution by overwriting', 'converting as a second step', similar to what I wrote in my EDIT section. I'd like to have it right directly after `read_delim` (or another call that would replace it)